# unbound identifier in module for Dr Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

Just trying to make a simple program to start to learn Scheme, and I keep on getting this error message. Here is my code:

```
    #lang racket

    (define (1+) (+ 1 x))
```

and I get the error "unbound identifier in module"

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out... I needed the variable in the name of it

```
    (define (1+ x) (+ 1 x))
```